# map.on('click') event disables the double click zoom

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a map that has an onclick event fired and displays a marker where the user has clicked. Problem is that this event seems to overrun the double click event. Because of this, when I double click the map, the map puts a marker and doesn't zoom. Anyone has an idea how I can solve this?

```
openmap = L.mapbox.map('map', 'julievelghe.nmjoj53p',{doubleClickZoom: true}).setView([49.152969, 6.473007], 5);

//on map click, create a marker
openmap.on('click',function(event){
    var coordinates = event.latlng;
    placeMarker(coordinates);
    alert("Single click");
});
```

Comment: A workaround might be to set a global timer in the map click handler and if a second one happens within so many MS (e.g. 20ms or so) then handle it as a double click event.  If not, handle as a single click event.  You could also try to tie into the `ondblclick` dom event to see if you can do the zoom there.  It just may turn into a manual process of zooming instead of automatic.

Answer (score 2):

This is what's happening in your code:

- First click lands on the map
- Marker is created
- Second click lands on the newly created marker

For a double-click to be triggered, the two individual click events must land in the same target. You can achieve this by making the marker non-interactive with the `{interactive: false}` option.

Keep in mind this behaviour is currently buggy in Leaflet 1.0.0-beta2, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3937 - you might want to use custom CSS classes for your markers and use `pointer-events: none` in your CSS.